# Custom font-color Field Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

The model has attribute status

```
status = fields.Selection([
    ('Progreso', 'En progreso'),
    ('Completa', 'Completa'),
    ('Anulada', 'Anulada'),
    ('En espera', 'En espera')
], 'Estado')
```

The view

```
<div class="card-text">
     <field name="status" />
 </div>
```

I would like each status have a particular font-color:

Progreso: Blue

Completo:Green

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this but you are limited to list of color.

```
<field name = 'status' widget="selection" decoration-danger="status=='Progreso'" decoration-info="status=='Completa'" decoration-muted="status=='Anulada'" decoration-success="status=='En espera'"/>
```

> decoration-bf - BOLD
>
> decoration-it - ITALICS
>
> decoration-danger - LIGHT RED
>
> decoration-info - LIGHT BLUE
>
> decoration-muted - LIGHT GRAY
>
> decoration-primary - LIGHT PURPLE
>
> decoration-success - LIGHT GREEN
>
> decoration-warning - LIGHT BROWN

You can try this too...

```
<field name = 'status' widget="selection" t-att-style="'color: #f00;' if status == 'Progreso' else ('color: #00f;' if status == 
     'Completa' else 'color: #696969;')" />
```

Comment: Great. You are amazing !